# TypeORM defining relationships and the extra name (I get columnNameColumnName)

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I have tried to find some instructions for this, but I can not figure it out.

I have two different tables:
One is a user table:

```
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, PrimaryColumn, Column, OneToMany, ManyToOne, JoinColumn} from "typeorm";
import {EUProfile} from "./EUProfile.entity";
import {EULogin} from "./EULogins.entity";
import {EUResponses} from "./EUResponses.entity";

@Entity()
export class EUUser {

    // EMAIL,ISACTIVE,NAME,PROFILEID,USERNAME
    @PrimaryColumn()
    userName: string;
    @Column("text")
    realName: string;
    @Column("text")
    contactEmail: string;

    @ManyToOne(type=>EUProfile, profile => profile.users)
    profileID: EUProfile[];
    @OneToMany(type => EULogin, login => login.userID) 
    users: EULogin[];
    @OneToMany(type => EUResponses, response => response.userName) 
    responses: EUResponses[];



}
```

The second one is a response table, with a relationship to that table:

```
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, PrimaryColumn, Column, OneToMany, ManyToOne, JoinColumn} from "typeorm";
import {EUUser} from "./EUUsers.entity";
import {EUSurvey} from "./EUSurvey.entity";
import {EUProfile} from "./EUProfile.entity";
import {EULogin} from "./EULogins.entity";


@Entity()
export class EUResponses {
    // EMAIL,ISACTIVE,NAME,PROFILEID,USERNAME
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    lineId: number;
    @ManyToOne(type=>EUUser, user => user.userName)
    userName: EUUser;
    @ManyToOne(type=>EUSurvey, survey => survey.surveyId)
    surveyId: EUSurvey;
    @Column("datetime")
    responseDate: Date;
    @Column("float")
    resAverage: number;
    @Column("smallint")
    resExperience: number;
    @Column("smallint")
    resSatisfaction: number;
    @Column("smallint")
    resSimplified: number;
    @Column("smallint")
    resSupport: number;
    @Column("smallint")
    resRoadmap: number;
    @Column("text")
    resUsageLength: string;
    @Column("text")
    resComment: string;







}
```

But whenever I try to access it, I get an error saying it can't find the field fieldNameFieldName, but where does it get the second fieldName:

> (node:55978) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: QueryFailedError:
> ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'EUResponses.userNameUserName' in
> 'field list'

For example, this query:

```
const alreadyThere = await responseRepository.findAndCount({
    where: { userName: cuResponse.userName,
            surveyId: cuResponse.surveyId
    },
    relations: ["userName", "surveyId"]
})
```

What I can not understand is, why does it constantly try to add 'UserName' to it, or am I misunderstanding what the OneToMany does. In laymans terms, I would expect it to mean (using userName in EUResponses as an example (so someone can correct me :) ).

```
 @ManyToOne(type=>EUUser, user => user.userName)
userName: EUUser;
```

1. for the value userName in EUResponses
2. There is a many to one relationship with EUUSer (type=>EUUser)
3. Stated userName should be matched against EUUser.userName (user.userName)

Clearly that is now what it is trying to do, but I can not figure out what, or is it just that I should refer to userName differently when searching or what?

And is the relations sections necessary?

Comment: You've specified that `userName` is primary key of for `EUUsers` so specifying it in the `@ManyToOne` decorator would be redundant. However, it isn't valid anyway because the second argument specifies the other end of the relationship in the target table. It should be `@ManyToOne(() => EUUser, user => user.responses) userName: EUUser: EUUser;`. I have to add that `userName` is an awful name for that property.

Comment: Sorry about the crappy property name :) . But this is where I am a bit lost. If it would be SQL foreign key, I would need to tell it what table to join, in the example above (EUUser), and what column to use to perform the match for the join (user.userName and then against what in current table (userName). But that does not seem to be what is happening?

Comment: `user.responses` is not a column, it is an array that corresponds to an implicit join in the generated SQL. The framework knows to join on the keys.